# Dynamic board of radiobuttons and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm extending game sniper. There were a premade table of radiobuttons. The point of game is to click checked radio button. I decided to ask user for board size and create a game board in js file. Unfortunately, after update I can't call it's property from script. I'm getting an error:

> Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined

When:

```
 document.targets.elements[mynum].checked=true;
```

That's how creating game board looks like:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    $("#board").append("<tr>");
    for(var j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            $("#board").append("td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\"><input type=\"radio\" onClick=\"hithead("+j+")\"></td>");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#board").append("td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\"><input type=\"radio\" onClick=\"hithead("+i+j+")\"></td>");
        }
    }
    $("#board").append("</tr>");
```

Do you have any idea how to change creating game board without loosing usefulness rest of code?

I would like to add that there is html file with some basic navigation and rest of file and game board should be placed in div container with id equals board, place where pre-definied were before. In js file I have rest of scripts which allows to play.

Regards.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle demo so we can test this ourselves?

Comment: Is it allow to paste a link to .rar file on hosting or should I use pastebin or something like this?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pXQrAnNd for html file
http://pastebin.com/quvhKgxb for js file